# Sharp drop in performance of SELECT ..  WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ..) with strings

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

**THE PROBLEM:**

```
SELECT new_filename
FROM tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames
WHERE new_filename
    NOT IN (SELECT filename FROM service.import_lightnings_filenames LIMIT 64500)
LIMIT 1;
```

Execution time: **62 ms**.

```
SELECT new_filename
FROM tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames
WHERE new_filename
    NOT IN (SELECT filename FROM service.import_lightnings_filenames LIMIT 65000)
LIMIT 1;
```

Execution time: **4.742 sec**.

(All LIMITS are only for test).

Enormous lag! And it increases exponentially.

**TABLES:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames (
  new_filename VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames_pkey PRIMARY KEY(new_filename)
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Table size: 7304 strings

Data example: `/xml/2012-07-13/01/01-24.xml`

```
CREATE TABLE service.import_lightnings_filenames (
  id SERIAL, 
  filename VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL, 
  imported BOOLEAN DEFAULT false, 
  strokes_num INTEGER, 
  CONSTRAINT import_lightnings_filenames_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX import_lightnings_filenames_idx
ON service.import_lightnings_filenames
USING btree (filename COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Table size: 70812 strings

Data example: `44;/xml/2012-05-26/12/12-18.xml;TRUE;NULL`

**QUERY PLANS:**

```
 Limit  (cost=0.00..2108.11 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=240.183..240.183 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=539, temp written=307
   ->  Seq Scan on tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=0.00..7698823.12 rows=3652 width=29) (actual time=240.181..240.181 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         Buffers: shared hit=539, temp written=307
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1946.82 rows=64500 width=29) (actual time=0.009..198.313 rows=64500 loops=1)
                 Buffers: shared hit=538, temp written=307
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1183.32 rows=64500 width=29) (actual time=0.005..113.196 rows=64500 loops=1)
                       Buffers: shared hit=538
                       ->  Seq Scan on import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=0.00..1299.12 rows=70812 width=29) (actual time=0.004..42.418 rows=64500 loops=1)
                             Buffers: shared hit=538
 Total runtime: 240.982 ms



  Limit  (cost=0.00..2125.03 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=30734.619..30734.619 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=547, temp read=112258 written=669
   ->  Seq Scan on tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=0.00..7760626.00 rows=3652 width=29) (actual time=30734.617..30734.617 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         Buffers: shared hit=547, temp read=112258 written=669
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1962.49 rows=65000 width=29) (actual time=0.798..42.306 rows=64820 loops=363)
                 Buffers: shared hit=543, temp read=112258 written=669
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1192.49 rows=65000 width=29) (actual time=0.005..116.110 rows=65000 loops=1)
                       Buffers: shared hit=543
                       ->  Seq Scan on import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=0.00..1299.12 rows=70812 width=29) (actual time=0.003..43.804 rows=65000 loops=1)
                             Buffers: shared hit=543
 Total runtime: 30735.267 ms
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You'd need to provide both query plans, because most probably, they differ (which may also answer your question right away).

Comment: The output of EXPLAIN **ANALYZE** (better yet: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE on, VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS on`) would tell us more than just EXPLAIN. Also, I don't see the point of your query. You are excluding 65000 filenames, but they are picked arbitrarily (no `ORDER BY`). From the rest that qualifies you pick one row, arbitrarily again. Please explain.

Comment: Of course a real query has no LIMIT. That's just for clearness.

Comment: The `limit 65000` in the subquery makes no sense to me. It is not clear, either.

Comment: That's because without limit the query takes several minutes long. Of course in the real application I don't apply these limits at all.

Comment: It will certainly generate a different plan. (especially Erwin's NOT EXISTS version). I suspect your estimated_cache_size is set too low, I'd expect index-scans. (probably random_page_size is set too high as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the performance drop seems to be that you run out of [**`work_mem`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) and the `materialize` step starts swapping out to disk. I quote the manual here:

> work_mem (integer)
>   [...] Hash tables are used in hash joins,
>   hash-based aggregation, and hash-based processing of **IN subqueries**.

Emphasis mine. Verify this by raising the setting for `work_mem` and running your queries once more. As @a_horse supplied in the comment, set it for the current session by calling:

```
set work_mem = '64MB';
```

You don't need your sysadmin for that. You can reset to the default within the session:

```
reset work_mem;
```

Setting will be gone with the end of the session. Change the setting in `postgresql.conf` (and reload) for a permanent effect.

Many PostgreSQL packages are shipped with very conservative settings (default 1MB). It very much depends on your workload, but 16 MB on a machine with 4 GB or more would be a minimum in general. I use 64 MB on a dedicated db server with 12 GB RAM - with only few concurrent users.

You may have to do some general tuning of your setup. Here is a list of pointers for [general performance optimization in the PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization). You will also find more information on `work_mem` tuning following the links.

---

Apart from this, rewriting your query will probably speed things up, too. `IN` subqueries with big lists tend to be the slowest choice in PostgreSQL.

#### LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

```
SELECT new_filename
FROM   tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames t
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT filename
    FROM   service.import_lightnings_filenames
    LIMIT  65000
    ) x ON t.new_filename = x.filename 
WHERE  x.filename IS NULL;
```

#### NOT EXISTS

Faster, in particular, with duplicates in `service.import_lightnings_filenames`:

```
SELECT new_filename
FROM   tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT filename
        FROM   service.import_lightnings_filenames
        LIMIT  65000
        ) x
    WHERE t.new_filename = x.filename 
    );
```

The same with **CTE** (probably not faster, but easier to read):

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT filename
    FROM   service.import_lightnings_filenames
    LIMIT  65000
    )
SELECT new_filename
FROM   tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   x
    WHERE  t.new_filename = x.filename 
    );
```

Comment: I had suspected this but hoped that this query doesn't resemble a too complex one (at the expense of indexes).
Thank you. I'll be able to try work_mem only tomorrow, with the sysadmin. And of course I'll tell about results.

Comment: You can change work_mem just for the session (e.g.: `set work_mem = '64MB'`). No need to do it in postgresql.conf

Comment: @AlexanderPalamarchuk: I added some more pointers. Sure looks like a case for more work_mem. Also, rewriting your query may improve performance. I added some alt. queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yeah, good idea for testing. I incorporated the hint, thanks.

Comment: So you're absolutely right, gentlements. With work_mem=64mb, without any limits: `Seq Scan on tmp2_import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=1476.15..1628.45 rows=3652 width=29) (actual time=110.713..111.809 rows=1130 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Buffers: shared hit=652
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on import_lightnings_filenames  (cost=0.00..1299.12 rows=70812 width=29) (actual time=0.005..46.125 rows=70812 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=591
 Total runtime: 113.436 ms`

Thank you very much, Erwin, for all your advices!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- SET work_mem=20000;
SET random_page_cost=1.1;
SET effective_cache_size=10000000;
```

Setting `work_mem` to 1--20 MB will prefer hash tables (as long as they fit in core) This is effective for small to moderate sized queries.

Setting `random_page_cost` lower will cause the query generator to prefer index scans once they are needed. This is the tripping point between the OP's first and second query. (but there, the index-scan stage is skipped, in favor of a seqscan) 
The default value( =4) is way too high)

`effective_cache_size` is an estimate of the amount of LRU buffering that the OS maintains. Set this as high as possible (without causing swapping)

Comment: A high value of `effective_cache_size` will never "cause swapping" as it is not a memory that Postgres allocates. It's "for informational purposes only" so to say. It gives the optimizer a hint on how probable it is, that data is in the file system cache.

Comment: I know that "swapping" is not the term. But the kind of "over committing" that results is similar in nature (the OS drops the blocks from the buffer cache. the DBMS pulls them in again, because it assumes they are still there)